# How does matplotlib knows what to display in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

The python code below will display pair plots of histogram and scatter-plots.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets

iris_dataset = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris_dataset.data
Y = iris_dataset.target

iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)
# create a scatter matrix from the dataframe, color by y_train
grr = pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=Y, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o',
                        hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8)

plt.show()
```

What puzzles me is how does `plt.show()` know what to display? `grr` was not seen to be assigned anywhere in the code into `plt`. How does `plt` magically knows what to display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas uses matplotlib to create its plots. The complete plot is already created by the `pandas.scatter_matrix` command.

The return of `pandas.scatter_matrix` is an array of matplotlib axes. This can be used to adjust the plot after creation.
However, this is not necessary as the complete plot already exist as a matplotlib figure.

When calling `plt.show()` any figure present in the matplotlib state machine is simply plotted. Since there is a figure present (=the one created by `pandas.scatter_matrix`), it will be shown.