# Imported pyplot module and called pyplot,plot() but didn't store the return to any variable. But calling pyplot.show() function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

From matplotlib library I have imported pyplot module. In that module there is an function plot() that I have used. Now my question is:

1. Why the plot() function is not within any class? And if it s within any class why didn't we create any object of the class and used the plot() function.
2. From the official documentation I learned that plot() returns a Line2D object. But the return of the plot() is not stored in any variable, yet we are using show() function. Generally it should be returned_object.show() but again the pyplot module has a show() function that is called without using any object just like plot() function. We are using just pyplot.show() to display the graph. How is it possible. I mean it makes more sense in either returned_object.show() or pyplot.show(the returned object from plot() function). How it shows that particular plot not the other random plot?

I have gone through the example code and plotted successfully. And in order to clear my doubts I have visited the official matplotlib module.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

years = [1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]

gdp = [300.2, 543.3, 1075.9, 2862.5, 5979.6, 10289.7, 14958.3]

# create a line chart, years on x-axis, gdp on y-axis
plt.plot(years, gdp, color='green', marker='o', linestyle='solid')

# add a title
plt.title("Nominal GDP")

# add a label to the y-axis
plt.ylabel("Billions of $")

plt.show()
```

Comment: A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398923/how-does-plt-show-know-what-to-show/48410495#48410495) and my answer to it shows a totally simplified mockup to make it transparent how pyplot works.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot) say that pyplot `is a state-based interface to matplotlib.`. It keeps the current state of your plot commands within itself  -like the current Axes, Figure, Artists...

From the [Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py):

> In matplotlib.pyplot various states are preserved across function
>   calls, so that it keeps track of things like the current figure and
>   plotting area, and the plotting functions are directed to the current
>   axes (please note that "axes" here and in most places in the
>   documentation refers to the axes part of a figure and not the strict
>   mathematical term for more than one axis).

---

The functions also return Artists, Lines, etc., so you can assign them to names and modify their properties to your hearts content.

---

It is worth reading through [the Tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html#tutorials) at least through the Legend Guide